# creating table using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Am I missing something here while creating table using sqlalchemy?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, DateTime

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password#@localhost:5432/LabData',echo=True)

metadata=MetaData(bind=engine)
main_table=('sample',metadata,
            Column('LIN',String(10),primary_key=True),
            Column('material_type',String(20),nullable=False),
            Column('source',String(20),nullable=False),
            Column('material_description',String(100)),
            Column('quantity',Integer),
            Column('location',String(2)),
            Column('received_by',String(20)),
            Column('received_date',DateTime,nullable=False),
            )

metadata.create_all()
```

The output on python console is:

```
2012-04-25 13:13:42,734 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select version()
2012-04-25 13:13:42,796 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2012-04-25 13:13:42,796 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select current_schema()
2012-04-25 13:13:42,796 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
```

When I try to add the data to the table, it says nosuchtableerror.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

possible typo?

```
main_table=('sample',metadata,...
```

maybe should be

```
main_table=Table('sample',metadata,...
#          ^^^^^
```